# Creating Models in Django

Tags: python, django-models

I am a a beginner learning django rest framework. I want to know if it is a good idea to create all my classes in one model file (model.py) of my app. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally start off having all of the models in a single models.py file. As the project gets larger and the app more complicated I'll sometimes end up breaking it out into multiple files (generally in a models directory).

An example of this is our user's app. We have multiple sets of users with different permissions in our website. Admin Users, Tour leaders, Suppliers, etc... Each one of these have been broken up into its own file to keep the logic contained.

```
users/
    models/
        __init__.py
        base.py // Stores the abstract User model used across all Users
        leaders.py // Stores specific models four Tour Leaders
        suppliers.py // Stores specific models for Suppliers
        money.py // Stores models related to how we pay Tour Leaders (lots of logic here)
    views.py
    forms.py
    urls.py
```

This allows us to contain all of the business logic into specific files, making it easier for developers to find what they want.

In our `__init__.py` file we import all of the models.

```
from users.models.base import *
from users.models.leaders import *
from users.models.suppliers import *
from users.models.money import *
```

Comment: It is an application with 4 tables in my database at the moment. I think i can separate them for future help.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't separate them until it's necessary. It just adds more cognitive overhead trying to find where things are stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but if you have quite a few models it's better to create a folder called `models/` inside your app, and put your models in there. You will also need to make a `__init__.py` file to import your models into for migrations to work (Django only expects to import `app.models`, and the `__init__.py` file handles that).

So your folder will look like:

```
models/
  __init__.py
  modelA.py
  modelB.py
  modelC.py
```

And your `__init__.py` will look like:

```
from .modelA import <modelName>
from .modelB import <modelName>
from .modelC import <modelName>
```